# If $f(tx,ty,tz)=t^4 f(x,y,z)$ and $f_{xx}+f_{yy}+f_{zz}=x^2+y^2+z^2$, can we find $f$?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

If $f(tx,ty,tz)=t^4 f(x,y,z)$ and $f_{xx}+f_{yy}+f_{zz}=x^2+y^2+z^2$, can we find $f$ ? (The OP is to find the surface integral for function $f$ on the entire unit sphere, but I think the first step is to find the function $f$ ?)

One possible solution is $f=\frac{1}{12}(x^4+y^4+z^4)$, but how to use the homogeneous condition to find or exclude other solutions? If set $t=0$, we have $f(0,0,0)=0$. Any hint will be appreciated?

Edit: thanks to the comment by @user85667

Do derivative respect to $t$,
$$xf_1(tx,ty,tz)+yf_2(tx,ty,tz)+zf_3(tx,ty,tz)=4t^3f(x,y,z)$$
then set $t=1$
$$xf_x(x,y,z)+yf_y(x,y,z)+zf_z(x,y,z)=4f(x,y,z)$$

How to procced next?

Comment: Or you can expand the polynomial in $t$, $f(tx,ty,tz)$, in powers of $t$ and use the identity principle. Each coefficient with degree of $t$ not $4$ must be zero.

Comment: I did it, but how to proceed next?

Comment: I think $f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{4} (x^2 y^2 + x^2 z^2 + y^2 z^2)$ would be another solution.

Comment: @user85667 The second condition does not imply that $f$ is a polynomial. You may consider $f+h,$ where $h$ is a harmonic function.

Comment: but harmonic function may not be homogeneous with degree 4 , right? @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: @MathFail I meant in my comment above  that the second condition itself does not lead to the polynomial.

Comment: @MathFail Well, for example $x^4 - 6 x^2 y^2 + y^4$ looks to me like a harmonic function which is homogeneous of degree 4.

Comment: Is the third argument $tz$ or $yz$?

Comment: Once we have a solution mentioned in OP, $f={1\over 12}(x^4+y^4+z^4)$ every solution is of the form $f+h,$ where $h$ is a harmonic function, homogeneous of degree $4.$