# Update: Contradictions when do integral $\unicode{x222F} ~f(x,y,z)~dS $, given $f(tx,ty,tz)=t^4 f(x,y,z)$ and $f_{xx}+f_{yy}+f_{zz}=x^2+y^2+z^2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $f(tx,ty,tz)=t^4 f(x,y,z)$ and $f_{xx}+f_{yy}+f_{zz}=x^2+y^2+z^2$, then compute the surface integral on the unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$:
$$\unicode{x222F} ~f(x,y,z)~dS $$

I try to find $f$ first, and asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523000/if-ftx-ty-tz-t4-fx-y-z-and-f-xxf-yyf-zz-x2y2z2-can-we-fin?noredirect=1#comment9502522_4523000). One possible solution is $f_p=\frac{1}{12}(x^4+y^4+z^4)$, but any solutions of the form $f=f_p+h$ where $h$ is a harmonic function and homogenous with degree $4$ (for example, $h=x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4$) will satisfy the given conditions. So it seems the solution for $f$ is not unique. Then how to solve this integral?

**Update**

Take solution $f=f_p+h$ by Mean Value Theorem, the integral on the harmonic function $h$ equals the value $4\pi h(0,0,0)$. Due to $h$ is homogeneous of degree $4$, we have $h(0,0,0)=0$, so the integral equals

$$I=\unicode{x222F} ~f_p~dS=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi f_p(\theta, \phi) \sin(\phi)d\phi d\theta$$

But the problem is this integral seems depends on the choice of $f_p$

If let $f_p=\frac{1}{12}(x^4+y^4+z^4),~~I=\frac{7\pi^2}{64}$

If let $f_p=\frac{1}{4}(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2),~~I=\frac{11\pi^2}{128}$

Do I make some mistakes?

Comment: Have you seen the mean value property of harmonic functions? What will $h(0)$ equal?

Comment: Hint: $\begin{equation}
h(x)= \frac 1{|{\partial B_r}|}\int_{\partial B_r(x)} h\, dS 
\end{equation}$

Comment: Thank you for the comment, yes, but it seems there is a contradiction (see my update)  @yona

Comment: Thank you, but it seems there is a contradiction (see my update)  @Matematleta

Comment: @MathFail I get $\pi/5$ for both. One of the integrals being $(1/12)\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(\phi)(\cos^4(\theta)\sin^4(\phi)+\sin^4(\theta)\sin^4(\phi)+\cos^4(\phi))\,d\phi\,d\theta$ and the other being $(1/4)\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(\phi)(\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)\sin^4(\phi)+\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)\cos^2(\phi))\,d\phi\,d\theta$.